# How do I customize the SharePoint 2010 claims based login page?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, authentication

I have a SharePoint 2010 web application that will be accessed by internal employees and outside partners which I would like to use the same url.

I have it set up for Claims based authentication with Windows and Forms based authentication enabled.  The default login page looks as follows:
[image]

I would like to edit the text in the drop-down menu to say "Internal Employees" instead of "Windows Authentication" and "External Partners" instead of "Forms Authentication" as well as change the red error image to the company logo.

Comment: Try this http://www.geektrainer.com/Blog/post/SharePoint-Custom-Logon-Page.aspx

Comment: updated link http://blog.geektrainer.com/2011/05/sharepoint-custom-logon-page.html

Comment: Check this out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2010/07/09/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind a javascript solution you can do something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/jXd2H/

```
var ddlLogin = document.getElementById("[drop down's client ID]");
ddlLogin.options[0].innerText = "Internal Employees";
ddlLogin.options[1].innerText = "External Partners";
```

You'll need to determine the client ID for the select box or if you know the server-side ID use `document.getElementById("<%=LoginTypeDropDown.ClientID %>");` (assuming server-side ID is `LoginTypeDropDown`)